# Redirect non https domains to http

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl

I have around 6-7 DOMAINS hosted on linode server where apache is a webserver. One domain is ssl configured and other runs on http only.

Suppose https://www.example.com is ssl configured .
 others are

```
http://www.example1.com 
http://www.example2.com
http://www.example3.com       
http://www.example4.com
```

What would be the dynamic rule if someone put https://www.example1.com or others get redirect to http://www.example1.com and so on

like in virtalhost setting for https something like

```
  <If "%{HTTP_HOST} != 'example.com'">
     Redirect permanent / http://%{HTTP_HOST}/
 </If>
```

above written hack doesn't work . any help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example1.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```